# Pass variable defined in JSP to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have defined a variable:

```
<% String envtoken= System.getProperty("token"); %>
```

and inside a `<uw:dropdown` tag I have an `onchange="functionName(this.form, '<%=envtoken %>');"`

I set a console.log in the javascript function and instead of printing the value of the variable it prints:

```
<%=envtoken %>
```

the html rendered is not rendered with the jsp variable content but like

```
functionName(this.form, '<%=envtoken %>')
```

Comment: Please give us more details. What is name of the file that contains your code? Where is that file located? Are you using Tomcat or some other web server? What is a <uw:dropdown tag ? Can you get a simple Hello World example JSP to work in your environment?

Comment: the html rendered is not rendered with the jsp variable content but like functionName(this.form, '<%=envtoken %>') @rickz

Comment: I understand that the JSP expression is not being evaluated.  In order to help you, we must know the answers to my questions.